# Ads code show blank space or not showing at all

Tags: jhtml

I try to add a module containing adsense code but it only shows blank space.

First i thought it is a google adsense issue so i tried using other ad networks and they all give me the same result or they wont show up.

than i thought it was a module issue so i tried many html extensions but nothing changed; they all start with a `<script>` tag, however i added a code from a ptc site that starts with `<a href` and it worked just fine.

so please can you help me add those ads code to my website.

Answer (score 1):

If your website is new, then note that Google doesn't play ads on new websites immediately. Google implemented this a long time ago to ensure that spam websites are filtered out and do not run ads from its network.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely filtering javascript.

If you are using the custom module:

- Go to Plugins > Editor - TinyMCE
- Remove "script" from the prohibited elements
- Add "script" to the valid elements

This will prevent that module stripping javascript.

If you are coding your own module using the `editor` field type, then make sure the filter is set to `raw`.

If the above does not work, please expand your answer to explain what module you are using, and also confirm that the code is being stripped from the editor as soon as you save it (as opposed to it appearing in the module's admin, but just not appearing on the front end.)

Comment: tahnks for reply ,,,, the above didn't work for me ,,, i tried modules like ads elite for adsense and now i'm using ""Flexi Custom Code"" extension ,,,, the code is not stripped in the module ,, i still can see it after i save it but in the front-end the ads don't load

Comment: Have you viewed the front-end source code? If the code is there but the ads not displaying, then it is likely that the problem is the script / adsense configuration and not Joomla.

Comment: yes you are probably right and yes i did check if the code exist but as i told you i tried many ad networks and not only adsense but none of them works so i thought it may be a joomla issue

Comment: and why the code that starts with <a href ,,,,,, > works just fine